Can't use alert or assign things to window in Nextjs
Are you trying to use the window object's built-in alert function to sanity test your application really quick and you keep getting errors like "Error: alert is not defined"?
import Image from "next/image";

alert('bruh');

export default function Home() {
  return (
        <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
        </main>
  );
}


Or maybe you're trying to assign something to window for some reason and you're getting a " ⨯ ReferenceError: window is not defined" in your terminal console?
window.propertyOnWindow = "inb4 'you shouldnt assign properties to window'";


Have you tried adding stuff to your nextConfig like:
const nextConfig = {
    webpack: (config, {isServer, externals})=>{
        config.externals.push('window');
        config.output.globalObject = "this";
        return config;
    }

};


to no avail?
You're in luck, because I just found the answer in an unrelated question.

Yeah there is no window on the server, therefore you must use a client component in order to access the window

All you have to do is add
'use client';


to the top of your (client facing) (jsx/ts/mdx) file. That really should be a specific error message instead of window is undefined.
